# A question about differentiability

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

So, this is the last subject I have to study for my exam on Friday, and I still can not comprehend how to prove that a function is differentable.

> $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
> (x^2 + y^2) \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right) & \text{ if }(x,y) \neq (0,0),\\
> 0& \text{ if }(x,y) = (0,0).
> \end{cases}$$
>   Is $f(x,y)$ differentiable at $(x,y) = (0,0)$?

I know that I have to calculate the partial derivative according to the definition and then do another limit, but I do not know the formulas for these.

I am very, very sorry for asking such a general question, but I am really in trouble and don't seem to understand it.

I would appreciate very much a thorough answer.

Comment: Why do you call this a "general" question? It seems qyite specific to me.

Comment: Because I do not even know how to start proving differentiability. I gave the question as one example

Comment: Some MathJax advice: Named math operators should appear upright, and the common ones have their own code for this purpose (e.g. `\sin`, `\log` - [see entry 11 in our MathJax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Is $$f(x)=x^2\sin\frac{1}x$$ differentiable at the origin? You're now looking at $f\circ g(x,y)$ where $g(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. What can you do now? Do you know how to apply the chain rule? Is $g$ differentiable (in the broader sense) at the origin?

**ADD** Note that to know the partial derivatives of your function, one really needs to calculate the partial derivatives "by hand". That is $$\eqalign{
  & {\left. {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}} \right|_{{x_0} = \left( {0,0} \right)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {h,0} \right) - f\left( {0,0} \right)}}{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} h\sin \frac{1}{{\left| h \right|}} = 0  \cr 
  & {\left. {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}} \right|_{{x_0} = \left( {0,0} \right)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {0,h} \right) - f\left( {0,0} \right)}}{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} h\sin \frac{1}{{\left| h \right|}} = 0 \cr} $$

So the partial deritvatives exist and are $0$. Thus, we now look at $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right) \to \left( {0,0} \right)} \frac{{\left| {f\left( {x,y} \right) - f\left( {0,0} \right) - \nabla f\left( {0,0} \right) \cdot \left( {x,y} \right)} \right|}}{{\left\| {\left( {x,y} \right)} \right\|}}$$

where ${\left\| {\left( {x,y} \right)} \right\|}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The above is $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right) \to \left( {0,0} \right)} \frac{{\left| {\left( {{x^2} + {y^2}} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} }}} \right)} \right|}}{{\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right) \to \left( {0,0} \right)} \left| {\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} \sin \left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} }}} \right)} \right| = 0$$ so the function is differentiable. We used that $x\sin \frac 1 x\to 0$.

Comment: The function is differentiable iff the last limit is equal to $0$?

Comment: @TheNotMe Yes. Differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Is proving differentiability to any other function follows the same equations and steps? Also, what if one of the partial derivative do not exist?

Comment: @TheNotMe Proofs may vary from function to function. If a partial derivative fails to exists, the function cannot be differentiable. In fact, if any directional derivative fails to exist at the point, the function cannot be differentiable there. This is because if the function was differentiable, the directional derivative $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x)$ would equal ${\bf Df}(x)(v)$.

Comment: And I remember there's a rule saying that if a function is not continuous at a certain point then it is not differentiable in it. Is this theory correct or is it in the other way or is it an iff?

Comment: If a function is differentiable at a point, it is continuous there. This means that if a function is not continuous, it cannot be differentiable. On the other hand, $|x|$ is continuous but not differentiable, so the assertion is not an "$\iff$".

Comment: Peter, thank you so much for your patience and thorough explanations. Thanks to you, now I know how to prove/disprove that a function is differentiable. If my professor brings a question like this in the exam on Friday, I will thank you again!
Good night!